# PHP redirect issue with the user of OR ||

Tags: php, session

I am forever redirected to access denied.php no matter what.. My user role is a user and 
my echo says it is a user as well..

```
  elseif (($_SESSION['role'] != 'user' || $_SESSION['role'] != 'admin'))
    {
    echo("<script>alert('You are not admin')</script>");
    header ("Location: access_denied.php");}
```

anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to be using `AND` since only one condition needs to be false for the statement to fail. It appears that you want both to fail for this code to be executed:

```
elseif (($_SESSION['role'] != 'user' && $_SESSION['role'] != 'admin'))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

As I can see in your script you are echo-ing output before the header(). This might be a problem.